# C++ Call a pointer within a caller

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to C++ and need to know how to use %data

```
    int ping = pNetChannel->GetPing(true);
if (ping < 500)
{
    float data = pNetChannel->GetPing(true);
    pNetChannel->Disconnect(eDC_Kicked,"High Ping: %data m/s");
}
```

This code is experimental and this is designed as an absolute limit for the server- a custom limit is manually specified in a config file elsewhere.

This code needs to disconnect the player and display the 'data' varible after the 'High Ping' part.

Thanks

Comment: `std::cout<<"High Ping: "<<data;`

Comment: `%data` as in C `printf("High Ping: %s m/s", data);` ?

Comment: 'pNetChannel->Disconnect(eDC_Kicked,"High Ping: %5.2f m/s", data);'- Tried this, just said that the function did not accept three arguments. And yes, it does return an integer (I've just corrected this).

Comment: Edited the title because it seems like the questions really was how to combine a string and a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how the **Disconnect** looks. Something like this would probably do what you want (assuming eDC_Kicked is of some class Status)

```
void Disconnect(Status _status, std::string _reason) { 
    // Do disconnect things
    ...
    // Print message
    std::cout << _reason << std::endl;
}
```

You would still have to construct your string (using a stringstream, for example) before sending it do the function, though:

```
if (ping < 500)
{
    float data = pNetChannel->GetPing(true);
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << data;
    std::string ping(oss.str());
    std::string reason = "High ping: " + ping;
    pNetChannel->Disconnect(eDC_Kicked, reason);
}
```

Alternatively, you could write the **Disconnect** in this way if it makes sense (and pass it both the string "High Ping: " and the float value, separately):

```
void Disconnect(Status _status, std::string _message, float _value) { 
     // Do disconnect things
     ...
     // Print message
     std::cout << _message << " " << _value << std::endl;
 }
```

But that might not be desireable if you don't have exactly one message and one variable every time etc. Also, you could use **printf** for printing if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly, you mean:

```
float data = pNetChannel->GetPing(true);
pNetChannel->Disconnect(eDC_Kicked,"High Ping: %5.2f m/s", data);
```

although it is inconsistend with:

```
int ping = pNetChannel->GetPing(true);
```

on the line before. Does `GetPing` return an integer or a float value?